# Function missing a positional argument

Tags: python

I've got the code below that is giving me the following error: `bubble_sort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a_list'`. I am passing a list to the function, so I do not know where the error is coming from. I am learning python right now, so understanding what I am doing wrong and the why is important to me.

```
import functools
import time

def sort_timer(func):
    """
    Timer function that counts how many seconds it takes the decoration function to run, in this case the sort functions
    described above. Returns the number of seconds using the time module.
    :param func:
    :return total_time:
    """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        Calculates the total time a function runs.
        :return:
        """

        total_time = None

        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()

        local_total_time = end_time - start_time

        return total_time

    return wrapper()

@sort_timer
def bubble_sort(a_list):
  """
  Sorts a_list in ascending order
  """
  for pass_num in range(len(a_list) - 1):
    for index in range(len(a_list) - 1 - pass_num):
      if a_list[index] > a_list[index + 1]:
        temp = a_list[index]
        a_list[index] = a_list[index + 1]
        a_list[index + 1] = temp

def main():

    random_list = [5,1,10,15,3,6,45,21,90, 76,44,33,41,27,81]

    print(bubble_sort(random_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: The bubble sort function works, it just didn't display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You are calling the `wrapper` function when you return it from `sort_timer`, but instead you should return the function without calling it.

```
return wrapper
```

2. You are printing the return value of the `bubble_sort` function, but that function doesn't return a value, so it just ends up printing `None`. Instead, you should print `random_list` after running `bubble_sort` on it.

```
bubble_sort(random_list)
print(random_list)
```

Here is your code with those fixes applied:

```
import functools
import time

def sort_timer(func):
    """
    Timer function that counts how many seconds it takes the decoration function to run, in this case the sort functions
    described above. Returns the number of seconds using the time module.
    :param func:
    :return total_time:
    """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        Calculates the total time a function runs.
        :return:
        """

        total_time = None

        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()

        local_total_time = end_time - start_time

        return total_time

    return wrapper

@sort_timer
def bubble_sort(a_list):
  """
  Sorts a_list in ascending order
  """
  for pass_num in range(len(a_list) - 1):
    for index in range(len(a_list) - 1 - pass_num):
      if a_list[index] > a_list[index + 1]:
        temp = a_list[index]
        a_list[index] = a_list[index + 1]
        a_list[index + 1] = temp

def main():
    random_list = [5,1,10,15,3,6,45,21,90, 76,44,33,41,27,81]
    bubble_sort(random_list)
    print(random_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running it produces the following output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 21, 27, 33, 41, 44, 45, 76, 81, 90]
```

Comment: As for why you need to return `wrapper` without calling it, I recommend reading the [Real Python article on decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

Comment: Thank you Jack! On another note, how did you change the code to display correctly? When I copied it, there was no issues with the indentation.

Comment: When writing/editing your question, highlight the code and click the code snippet button (it looks like `{}`). This indents the code using four spaces, which is what Stack Overflow uses to distinguish code from regular text. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer. :)